# Is this an example of 2-way databinding in React using Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I believe it is because it binds the value back to the property inputText but just want to make sure I'm stating this correctly.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InputElement = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter Some Text"
        onChange={e => {
          setInputText(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of 2 way data binding because when you update the state, the UI changes, and when the UI changes, the state changes. Just need to remind you to set the `value` prop on the `<input>` element to `inputText` so that it's a controlled component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InputElement = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="Enter Some Text"
        onChange={e => {
          setInputText(e.target.value);
        }}
        value={inputText}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputElement;
```

Comment: Yes, setting value. I just too carried away in my "stripping down" the example